The "intersection" (in a sense) of the $\mathbb{Q}_p$s
Below, for $\rho$ a Cauchy sequence in a complete metric space $\mathcal{X}$, I write "$\lim^\mathcal{X}\rho$" for the limit of $\rho$ in $\mathcal{X}$.
I recently taught a class including a brief unit on the $p$-adic numbers, $\mathbb{Q}_p$. I was careful to say that if $x\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $y\in\mathbb{Q}_q$ with $p\not=q$ then we can't (generally) meaningfully compare $x$ and $y$. However, this raised the following question:
Let $\mathscr{A}$ (for "all") be the set of sequences of rational numbers which are Cauchy with respect to the $p$-adic norm for every prime $p$ (other than the "real prime" of course), modded out by the relation $\sigma\approx\tau$ iff $\lim^{\mathbb{Q}_p}\sigma=\lim^{\mathbb{Q}_p}\tau$ for every prime $p$. For example, we have an obvious injection-of-sets $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow\mathscr{A}: q\mapsto [(q)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}]_\approx$, but this is not surjective (e.g. consider $(1+\sum_{i=1}^ni!)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$). Moreover, we can view $\mathscr{A}$ as a ring by interpreting addition/subtraction/multiplication "componentwise."
My question is whether we can describe $\mathscr{A}$, at least as an abstract ring, in a snappier way: that is, can we describe $\mathscr{A}$ up to isomorphism in terms which don't refer to the $p$-adic norms?
(More generally, for $F$ a filter on the set of primes let $\mathscr{A}_F$ be the set of sequences of rationals which for some $I\in F$ are Cauchy with respect to $\Vert\dots\Vert_p$ for each $p\in I$, modded out by the equivalence relation given by $\sigma\approx_F\tau$ iff for some $I\in F$, we have $\lim^{\mathbb{Q}_p}\sigma=\lim^{\mathbb{Q}_p}\tau$ for all $p\in I$. I'm broadly interested in the $\mathscr{A}_F$s as a whole, as well as the way they "fit together" via the obvious homomorphisms $\mathscr{A}_G\rightarrow\mathscr{A}_F$ for $G\supseteq F$; $\mathscr{A}=\mathscr{A}_{\{\mathsf{primes}\}}$ just seems like a good first step.)

For any $\sigma\in\mathscr A$ and any prime $p$, is $\lim^{\mathbb Q_p}\sigma\in\mathbb Q$?

I agree with @TorstenSchoeneberg, I would guess $\mathbb Q=\mathscr A$.

"Other than the 'real prime', of course": it's not clear from the front cover of the book linked behind a £150 paywall what the 'real prime' actually refers to!

@TorstenSchoeneberg Whoops, yes - thanks! Fixed.

@KentaS See my reply to Torsten.

The $A$ is just the product of all the $\mathbf{Q}_p$.
You can even include $p = \infty$ if you want. Let
$$y = (y_p) \in \prod \mathbf{Q}_p$$
Chose some ordering of your places/primes. Then, by weak approximation (or the Chinese remainder theorem in this case), there
exists an element $x_n \in \mathbf{Q}$ which is (for whatever fixed norm you chose)
within $2^{-n}$ of $y_p$ for the first $n$ places. Then $x_n$ will converge to $y_p$ in $\mathbf{Q}_p$ for any $p$. By definition, the kernel is trivial, so this is an isomorphism.

Ah of course! Nice answer!
